# Mount a directory from an already-mounted remote share directory

Tags: mount, nfs

I have a remote machine at IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, and a local machine. I've set up the export file on the remote machine to export /ShareDir.

On my local machine, I can run `mount xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ShareDir /mnt/MountShareHere` just fine. I can go into /mnt/MountShareHere and see everything from /ShareDir in it.

Now I want to mount a directory from inside /mnt/MountShareHere to the local filesystem. First I tried `mount /mnt/MountShareHere/Subdir /mnt/MountSubdirHere` which returned `mount: you must specify the filesystem type`. So I tried `mount -t nfs /mnt/MountShareHere/Subdir /mnt/MountSubdirHere`, which gave me `mount.nfs: remote share not in 'host:dir' format`.

I *could* just mount Subdir the same way I mounted /ShareDir (using the IP address and the path to Subdir on the remote machine), but I'd rather not (I'd have to rewrite some scripts and I'm lazy). Is there a trick to this? If not, what's the reason this can't be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do a `--bind` mount:

```
sudo mount -B /mnt/MountShareHere/Subdir /mnt/MountSubdirHere
```